# Wallet as daemon, what's the security-concern about "rpcallowip"?

Tags: wallet, daemon

When running (btc-/ltc-/whatever) wallet as daemon, I have to set "rpcuser" and "rpcpassword".

There is the option "rpcallowip", it is recommended to have this value very strict, e.g. "127.0.0.1".

I cannot see any danger setting this value to "*.*.*.*" - if anyone guesses my server and credentials, he/she is welcome to mine for my wallet.

So, is there any danger opening rpcallowip?

Comment: I'm not sure if the * is allowed, but as a general rule it would seem thatthe danger is in the scope of the RPC and what it can do.

Comment: * (Wildcard) is allowed, I tested suggested setup. Common usecase for wildcard ist 192.168.0.*, but *.*.*.* works, too.

Answer (score 3):

> if anyone guesses my server and credentials, he/she is welcome to mine
>   for my wallet.

He/she can also call all other RPC commands. For example, `sendtoaddress`. So, if your wallet is unlocked you can loose your coins.

Comment: Of course, that is right.